# Add extra row to SQL query without specifying all columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table 'Customers' which has about 30 columns of data. This comes from a 3rd party data source, so I have no control over the number of columns or ability to insert into the table.

```
Select * from customers
```

What I would like to do in my query is a get a full list of customers, plus *one* extra row where I can link transactions to an 'unkonwn' customer.

On the extra row, I'd like to define just a few columns and have the remaining be blank.

```
SELECT -1 customer_id, 'No Customer' customer_name FROM DUAL
```

So essentially I need all records from the customer table, plus one additional 'dummy' record where all columns are null EXCEPT for the customer_id and customer_name

This can be accomplished with a UNION, however that requires you to explicitly define all of the unused columns as NULL. This is a problem because the 3rd party may add additional columns in the future which would break the query.

Is there any way to add an extra row to a query (union a row) without explicitly defining ALL columns, and instead define only the columns I don't want as NULL?

Example:

```html
<h1>
Existing Customer table:
</h1>

<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>Customer_id</th><th>customer_name</th><th>customer_city</th><th>customer_industry</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>5453</td><td>Apple Inc.</td><td>Cupertino</td><td>Technology</td></tr>
 <tr><td>7865</td><td>Union Pacific</td><td>Omaha</td><td>Shipping</td></tr>
</tbody></table>

<h1>With extra data</h1>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>Customer_id</th><th>customer_name</th><th>customer_city</th><th>customer_industry</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>5453</td><td>Apple Inc.</td><td>Cupertino</td><td>Technology</td></tr>
 <tr><td>7865</td><td>Union Pacific</td><td>Omaha</td><td>Shipping</td></tr>
 <tr><td>-1</td><td>Unknown Customer</td><td>[NULL]</td><td>[NULL]</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: I've added an example.snippet. As you can see I added 1 extra row to the table. This is a bit simplified since the customer table has about 30 columns and can have additional rows added at any time.

Comment: Does this have to be done at the SQL level? Do you have access only to the SQL query and not the result set?

Comment: It has to be done in the SQL query, since i don't have access to insert the records into he source table.

Comment: @corycorycory I know you have no access to insert, but do you also not have access to the select query result? Are you retrieving the query result in another programming language (e.g. python), or are there additional processing steps in SQL after you get the result?

Comment: You should not do that on sql level. You should better do that on application level. Since you've put this html table - that means you have some application that fethcs data, so you need to modify that application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `customer_id` and `customer_name` are the first two columns, you can do:

```
select x.customer_id, x.customer_name, c.* except (customer_id, customer_name)
from (select -1 as customer_id, 'No Customer' as customer_name) x left join
     customer c
     on 1 = 0;
```

The `except` functionality is quite useful in BigQuery.

Comment: This did the trick! Didn't realize there was an 'except' clause :)

Answer (score 4):

Gordon's solution is great [as always :o)] but it still has solid drawback - it heavily depends on order of columns in `customer` table. Meaning if customer_id and customer_name are not two first columns in `customer` table that solution will fail if you will union it with original query.

Namely, below (as an example) will either fail or just will misplace columns (if types are match):

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.customer` AS (
  SELECT 'many other columns here' other, 1 customer_id, 'abc' customer_name 
)
SELECT x.customer_id, x.customer_name, c.* EXCEPT (customer_id, customer_name)
FROM (SELECT -1 AS customer_id, 'No Customer' AS customer_name) x 
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.customer` c
ON 1 = 0 
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.customer`
```

To address this issue, you should use yet another quite useful in BigQuery feature -

```
SELECT * REPLACE()
```

so below is example (BigQuery Standard SQL) of solution to address above described issue

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.customer` AS (
  SELECT 'many other columns here' other, 1 customer_id, 'abc' customer_name 
)
SELECT c.* REPLACE(-1 AS customer_id, 'No Customer' AS customer_name)
FROM (SELECT 1) x 
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.customer` c
ON 1 = 0 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.customer`
```

as you can see, above have no dependency on columns order and always return result with original schema of `customer` table

Comment: This is also a great solution. Thank you!